# Is Qml Calendar component going crazy?

Tags: calendar, qml

Before to open a bug to the Qt project, I'd like to ask you if I'm doing something wrong or the Qml Calendar is really going crazy.

It follows the code which can be used to test it:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 768

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 8

        Calendar {
            id: calendar
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            weekNumbersVisible: true
            selectedDate: new Date("2015/01/01")
            frameVisible: true
            focus: true

            onVisibleMonthChanged: visibleMonthChangedRef.currDate = visibleYear+"/"+visibleMonth
            onVisibleYearChanged: visibleYearChangedRef.currDate = visibleYear+"/"+visibleMonth
        }

        Label {
            id: visibleMonthChangedRef
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            property string currDate: ""
            text: "onVisibleMonthChanged -> " + currDate
            Component.onCompleted: font.pointSize = font.pointSize*2
        }

        Label {
            id: visibleYearChangedRef
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            property string currDate: ""
            text: "onVisibleYearChanged -> " + currDate
            Component.onCompleted: font.pointSize = font.pointSize*2
        }
    }
}
```

Easy going, start the application and you'll see a calendar as well as a couple of labels that report information about the `visibleMonth` and the `visibleYear` as provided by the `Calendar` component.
Those labels are filled accordingly to the `onVisibleYearChanged` and `onVisibleMonthChanged` of the `Calendar`.
The selected date is 2015/01/01.

Well, go back of a month towards the 2014.

The `onVisibleYearChanged` looks to be right while accessing the `visibleMonth` and `visibleYear` properties of the `Calendar`, while the `onVisibleMonthChanged` looks to me as living in a far future.

Now, try to move on of a month towards the 2015.

Again, while the `onVisibleYearChanged` is still behaving the right way, the `onVisibleMonthChanged` is accessing a `Calendar` component that is sitting in the past.

You can go back and forth over the new year and a function that is reacting to the signal `onVisibleMonthChanged` will never behave properly for it looks to me as invoked once all the internal properties have not been properly set yet.

That said, am I doing something wrong and thus the problem is within my code (of course, the one above is a small example from a more complex project) or I've really found a bug in the 'Calendar` component and I should proceed opening a ticket to the Qt project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it looks a bit strange to me asking to modify a component, being notified that it's updated, thus find that my changes have been only partially set (a kind of work in progress notification), that's it.

It seems that the error was in my expectations. :-)

Once the `month` moves on or back over the `year` (that is, from December to January and vice versa), the `Calendar` component correctly updates the `property visibleMonth` and the `property visibleYear`.

Anyway, the are no guarantees that the corresponding signals (`onVisibleMonthChanged` and `onVisibleYearChanged`) are emitted once the internal representation has been updated as a whole.

Actually, the former is emitted when the changes to the second property are still pending, thus querying the `visibleYear` property in a listener ends with the *wrong* year (or at least, a one not updated yet).

As an example of solution, the user of the component can work around this odd behavior by attaching a listener to both the signals, even though I strongly suspect the out there a better solution is waiting for me.

I'll manage to find an alternative approach.
Thank you for all of your responses.